# How do i show the attributes of my table/relation in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, relation

I have transferred the contents of one table to another table. I want to ensure the second table I created is identical in content and attributes. 
How do I display the schema/attributes of my table?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command to use:

```
.SCHEMA [table]
```